# How to clone the version of code on each commit from github?

Tags: github, version, checkout

I'm working on an application developed on github. I need to clone a separate copy of each version  of the repository. For example, if I have 15 commits I should have also 15 versions of the code on my pc. I clone the project and then I execute the command git checkout :

```
git clone https://github.com/nirhart/shortrain.git
git checkout 86b403574c90f16b77da4bef8d67a71471ad7f77
```

It return an error :

```
 not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

Comment: Please fix the spelling error in the title!

Comment: FIxed spelling and grammar, and tried to use appropriate vocabulary to describe what you want to do. It might help to discuss *why* you want to do this.

Comment: I fixed all my errors.Thanks!

Comment: My question is: if I clone the shortrain application from github and I cd it to execute the `git checkout <idCommit>`, it return for me the version of code on each commit, I mean a file that contain the version of code for this commit